# Format a date - without time?

Tags: php

I have a date:

```
30/12/2010
```

I use:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input['date']);
```

But this outputs:

```
2010-12-30 21:15:37
```

How can I output just the date and not the time?

Comment: So how are you actually outputting it? because `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input['date']);` doesn't generate any output

Comment: [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) returns a [`DateTime` object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Use the [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to format the output to your liking.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a "!" before the format string.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', $input['date']);
```

This will set the time to midnight.

Comment: Yes, the **php.net** user contributed notes clearly state that putting ! before the date format string will set the time to 00:00:00, currently in the second user contributed note here: [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: ^This neat trick is no longer mentioned in a user note contribution. It's properly documented in [DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your solution is in your question. createFromFormat method return to us a DateTime object.You can use it to print formatted date time.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input['date']);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: No. Because i guess, your $input['date'] variable content is not a DateTime object, it is only string. There are an DateTime object to use format method.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the 21:15:37 to be the current time. You don't have to display the time, or you can reset it - to 00:00:00 for example, if you wanted to.

```
// public DateTime DateTime::setTime ( int $hour , int $minute [, int $second = 0 ] )
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input['date']);
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");  // or other format
```

Comment: I'd rather not display it, how can I do this?